# Entity Framework Link Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In my database I have the following three tables:

**Order**
OrderID
OrderDate
...

**Item**
ItemID
ItemName
...

**OrderItems**
OrderID
ItemID
Quantity
...

OrderItems is a Link / Join table. I have an MVC page where I want to retrieve an Order and display everything that was ordered. I create a query like so:

```
var order = (from o in db.Orders.Include("OrderItems.Item")
             where o.OrderID == id
             select o).SingleOrDefault();
```

Now I have a viewmodel that looks like:

```
public class OrderViewModel {
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get the query I created to extract the Items from the OrderItems collection?

**Edit**
What I really would like is if my model didn't even have this entity at all. I would like my entities to be:

Order
Item

The Order entity would have a collection of Items directly, instead of having to go through the OrderItems to get to the Item. I'm not sure if this is possible, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
var order = (from o in db.Orders             
             where o.OrderID == id              
             select new OrderViewModel()                          
               {                             
                 Order = o,                             
                 Items = o.OrderItems.Select(i => i.Item)
               }).SingleOrDefault();
```

You don't need to call `Include` to use navigation properties in query and because you are projecting result you most probably do not need to load navigation properties in `Order`.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
var order = (from o in db.Orders.Include("OrderItems.Item")
             where o.OrderID == id
             select new OrderViewModel()
                        {
                            Order = o,
                            Items = o.OrderItems.Item    //maybe o.OrderItems.Item.ToList()
                        } ).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Doesn't work. OrderItems doesn't have an Item property because it is a collection.